# I made paint program with pyqt5 but when I maximize the window, the pointer is drawing in another location

Tags: python, pyqt5

I made window with pyqt5 as paint program the problem that when I maximize the window the pointer is drawing in another location so there is distance between the line drawn and the curser,I noticed that when I minimize it to 800 * 600 the pointer is drawing well, so how can I draw correctly in maximized window ?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
QColorDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
 
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

# window class
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # title
        self.setWindowTitle("linuxPaint")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('edit.ico'))

       
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
        self.showMaximized()

        # creating image object to draw on
        self.image = QImage(self.size(), QImage.Format_RGB32)

        self.drawing = False
        self.brushSize = 2
        self.brushColor = Qt.black

        # we use QPoint follow the mouse pointer
        self.lastPoint = QPoint()

        # creating menubar
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()

        # adding brush color to main menu
        brush_color = mainMenu.addMenu("Colors")

     
        # creating action for black color
        black = QAction("Black", self)
        # adding this action to the brush colors
        brush_color.addAction(black)
        # connect methods to the black so when you click on black you select blackColor
        black.triggered.connect(self.blackColor)

        chooseColors = QAction("Choose Color", self)
        brush_color.addAction(chooseColors)
        chooseColors.triggered.connect(self.on_color_clicked)
        # chooseColors.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    # method for checking mouse clicks
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        # if left mouse button is pressed
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # make drawing true
            self.drawing = True
            # make last point to the point of cursor
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()

    # method for tracking mouse activity
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):

        # checking if left button is pressed and drawing flag is true
        if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) & self.drawing:
            
            # creating painter object
            painter = QPainter(self.image)
            
            # set the pen of the painter
            painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize,
                            Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            
            # draw line from the last point of cursor to the current point
            # this will draw only one step
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            
            # change the last point
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            # update
            self.update()

    # method for mouse left button release
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):

        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # make drawing flag false
            self.drawing = False

    # paint event
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # create a canvas
        canvasPainter = QPainter(self)
        # canvasPainter.setRenderHint(PyQt5.QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        
        # draw rectangle on the canvas
        canvasPainter.drawImage(self.rect(), self.image, self.image.rect())


    # methods for changing brush color
    def blackColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.black

    def whiteColor(self):
        self.brushColor = Qt.white

    def on_color_clicked(self):
        color = QColorDialog.getColor()

        if color.isValid():
            self.brushColor = color

# create pyqt5 app
App = QApplication(sys.argv)

# create the instance of our Window
window = Window()

# showing the window
window.show()

# start the app
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: The problem is that you're not drawing to a window, you are drawing to a bitmap -- a QImage.  You set the size of the QImage to 800x600 at initialization, and it stays that size forever.  When you change the size of the window, the system helpfully stretches that image to fit the screen, so pixels become larger.  You need to handle size change events, and resize your QImage to match.

Comment: trying `print(self.size())` after `self.showMaximized()`. `showMaximized` might be enqueued to run once `App.exec()` is called

Comment: @Tim Roberts
thanks for your reply,
so how can I resize the window and the image still with same size like in paint program in windows

Comment: @SargeATM printing the size right after showing will not suffice, as the window manager could require some event loop iterations until the "final" size is reached.

Comment: @AbdallahEldesouky do not implement painting in the main window. Use a QWidget subclass (set as central widget) and override both mouse and painting in it.

Comment: You can implement `resizeEvent` to catch the size change.  You can re-allocate your QImage there.

Comment: @musicamante That is my point exactly because that is the size that the QImage is getting initialized with.